# Attribute level authorization in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, frameworks, attributes, authorization

I'm using [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) for authentication and I'm looking for an authorization framework that lets me declare edit permissions for specific model attributes.

I have three different roles in my app: Teacher, Parent, and Student. The Student model belongs_to Family. When a Teacher creates a Student, they are able to set the Family association. When a Parent visits the edit page for a Student, however, they should not be able to change that association, only view it.

In the view, it's easy to alter the form depending on who is viewing it (disable or don't disable the family select input, for example) but a crafted form can get around that. What I need is something that will throw some kind of authorization exception when someone tries to change an attribute that they are not allowed to change.

I'm currently looking at [declarative_authorization](https://github.com/stffn/declarative_authorization), but it seems it's not fine-grained enough to restrict changes to attributes, only the model as a whole.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ended up using the new [MassAssignmentSecurity](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/MassAssignmentSecurity/ClassMethods.html) feature, although it looks like it might not work that great in conjunction with accepts_nested_attributes_for.

Answer (score 0):

I realize my answer comes 2 years late. For what it's worth what you need is an authorization framework that is fine-grained enough.

XACML, the standard from OASIS provides just that. It can handle any number of attributes.

See my detailed answer here: [Rails 4 authorization gem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20299354/rails-4-authorization-gem/20310178#20310178)