# Authorization in rails4+

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authorization

I have a User table where i store user information and i have a Role table where i store the roles. The associations of the tables is : User can have just one role, and roles can have more than one User.
I have my controller where i have actions like "create, new, update, delete". I want to use authorization for these actions. For example admin can do everything, a simple user can just read etc. Im very new in RoR, can somebody tell me how to permit/restrict access to specific pages/actions based in roles.

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails 4 authorization gem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20299354/rails-4-authorization-gem)

Comment: Im trying to use one of them, but it stops all the applications, they are so messed up.  I was wondering if there is a method with queries or something.

Answer (score -1):

The [CanCanCan gem](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan) is designed for this task.

I would also recommend considering the gem [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) for user authentication, rather than rolling your own solution.