# Rails 5 with Devise, testing Controllers with Rspec (destroy action)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, factory-bot, rspec-rails

I am implementing rspec test for `destroy` action, the concept is that signed in user can only destroy his own posts, and cannot destroy posts creates by other users.

```
The `new_post` is created by a user named `creator`, and another user named `user1` signed in and try to delete the `new_post`, it should not be able to delete it, because of the `  before_action :authenticate_user!, only: %i[create destroy]` in Posts controller
```

## Posts controller.

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_post, only: %i[show edit update destroy]
  before_action :current_user, only: %i[create destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, only: %i[create destroy]
  .
  .
  .

  def destroy
    @post.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to posts_url, notice: 'Post was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private

  def set_post
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  
  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:content, :picture)
  end
end
```

## users controller spec

```
require 'rails_helper'
RSpec.describe PostsController, type: :controller do
  context  'DELETE #destroy' do

    let(:user1) {User.create!(name:"John", email:"john@mail.com", password:"password")}

    let(:creator) { User.create!(name: "creator", email: "creaor@gmail.com", password: "password") }

    let(:new_post){creator.posts.create!(content: "Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum")}

    
    it 'A user cannot delete a post created by other user' do
      sign_in user1
      p (new_post)
      expect { delete :destroy, params: { id: new_post.id } }.to change(Post, :count).by(0)
      
    end
  end
end
```

## Failures:

```
  1) PostsController DELETE #destroy A user cannot delete a post created by other user
     Failure/Error: expect { delete :destroy, params: { id: new_post.id } }.to change(Post, :count).by(0)
       expected `Post.count` to have changed by 0, but was changed by -1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need to add an *authorization* check to your code. `authenticate_user!` *authenticates* that the person making the request is logged in. However, it does not check if the user is *authorized* to make the request they're making.

See [Authentication versus Authorization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6556522/authentication-versus-authorization) for a bit more discussion on the two concepts. And take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/25654844/868533 for a good overview of popular authorization gems in Rails. To be clear, you almost definitely want a way to authenticate users (`Devise`) along with an authorization gem.

Assuming you decide to go with `CanCanCan` (which is a common option that I've used in past), you'd add an `Ability` class like:

```rb
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    if user.present?
      can :destroy, Post, user_id: user.id
    end
  end
end
```

Then you could add `before_action :check_authorization, only: %i[destroy]` as a new `before_action` on your controller and your tests should pass without any modification.

Comment: cancancan or pundit are some notable options.

Comment: Thank you for clarification, that's what I really need, it was authorization and not only  authentication, so I just created a simple `#authorized?`  method  and the test passed `def authorized?
    redirect to root_path unless @post.user_id == current_user.id
  end`

Answer (score 1):

Remember. you are writing a controller test. So this test is `unit test`. There are two main ways to authorize in `Devise`. They are authorize routes and authorize controller. If you using authorize routes, when you write rspec for controller, you must use `stub` to counterfeit an authorize access.

Comment: Thank you for clarification, that's what I really need, it was authorization and not only authentication, so I just created a simple #authorized? method and the test passed def authorized? redirect to root_path unless @post.user_id == current_user.id end